# In Python3/tkinter how to set the size of a frame relative to its parent window size?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, window

In Python3/tkinter is there a simple way to set the size of a `ttk.frame` as being relative to its parent window size and ensure that it will adjust properly (with all its widgets) on window resize?

As a bit of context, I am trying to `pack()` a `ttk.frame` a few pixels smaller than the `root` window width.

Comment: There is no single answer to this question. Making a frame a size relative to the parent can be accomplished many ways. It depends on what is in the frame, what is in the parent frame, how these frames use pack, grid or place, how you want extra space to be handled, etc. This question is simply too broad as written.

Comment: he does especify the use of pack though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the size you want and have it you do:

```
root = # Your root window
myFrame = ttk.Frame(root, height=desiredHeight, width=desiredWidth)
myFrame.pack()
```

So if you want it relative to the root:

```
root = # Your root window
rootHeight = root.winfo_height()
rootWidth = root.winfo_width()
# Say you want it to be 20 pixels smaller
myFrame = ttk.Frame(root, height=rootHeight-20, width=rootWidth-20)
myFrame.pack()
# OR
myFrame = ttk.Frame(root) # No set dimensions
myFrame.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
# This will make it have a padding of 20 pixels on height and width,
# with respect to parent rather than itself
```

Comment: Seems to be prety simple after all. Would it be also possible to make it relative to parent (like in your last 2 code lines) if we were using `place()` instead of `pack()`?

Comment: I tryed out a little, and with `place()` we can get a similar effect using something like this (in this case i am playing the new frame with position relative to another object): `FRAME.place(in_=OTHER_OBJECT, relx=.95,  y=0, anchor="se", relwidth=.9)`. This way, we get a frame tear has 90% the window width and is positioned with 5% horizontal space on both sides, right and left.

Comment: that is a good idea too, but be carefull, the `place` geometry manager is muuuuch more simplistic so whereas for this specifically its  a good idea, usually its best to avoid it

Comment: I am still learning about it, but for now I am sticking more with a combination  of pack and grid, for general use, following the kind sugestions of some stackoverflow users. But in fact, for one specific situation (a popup frame that appears on top of other frase) I have been using `place` as suggested by @Bryan Oakley, and it works great.